# Glassfish4 gzip encoding issue (corrupted responses)

Tags: java, glassfish, gzip

Glassfish4 after GZIP enabling works wrong.
All the responses after ~12kb are corrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is internal Glassfish issue.
The solution could be found here. https://java.net/jira/browse/GRIZZLY-1535

- Just download `nucleus-grizzly-all.jar`
- stop domain
- replace existing jar in `glassfish\modules` with downloaded one
- clear osgi-cache (just remove everything in `glassfish\domains\YOUR_DOMAIN\osgi-cache\felix`)
- start domain.